# How to pass struct by reference in C++?

Tags: c++, list, struct

I have just started learning C++.

I am trying to create a linked list without the use of class. So, in the main function, I have head and tail pointer. After that, I am asking the user for the task to be performed. User has to enter A, if he wants to add a new student. To print the list, user has to enter P and to quit the program. I have written the following program to achieve the task:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Student {
    string name;
    Student* next;
};

void add_student(Student *, Student *);
void print_list(Student *);

int main()
{   
    Student *head, *tail;
    head=NULL;
    tail=NULL;

    while (true) {
        cout << "\nOptions:\n";
        cout << "To add Student [A]\n";
        cout << "To print Student list [P]\n";
        cout << "Quit Q  [Q]\n";

        string choice = "";
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice.compare("A") == 0) {
            add_student(head, tail);
            cout << "Book successfully added.\n";
        }
        else if (choice.compare("P") == 0) {
            print_list(head);
        }
        else if (choice.compare("Q") == 0) {
            cout << "Bye!";
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Invalid choice.\n";
        }
    }
}

void add_student(Student *head, Student *tail)
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter name of student \n";
    cin >> name;

    Student *temp = new Student;
    temp->name = name;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        tail=temp;
        temp=NULL;
    }
    else
    {   
        tail->next=temp;
        tail=temp;
    }

    // Check student has been added successfully.
    print_list(head);
}

void print_list(Student *head)
{
    cout << "Student list is as following:\n";
    Student *temp=new Student;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
      cout<< temp->name <<"\n";
      temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

However, the problem is every time a new student is added it is added as the first element in the list instead of adding it at the last. I think, I am doing some mistakes with Pass by reference.

Request you to please check and suggest me where am I doing the mistake. It would be of great help, because I am a begineer in C++ and I really want to learn from my mistakes.

Comment: `head=temp` in `add_student` does nothing useful as head is a local variable, a copy of the passed pointer

Comment: Thanks. I will take care from next time. Could you please help me identify my mistake.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh okay. Thanks. What should I change so that it changes the head in the main function as well.

Comment: pass the pointer by reference that should work: `void add_student(Student *&head, Student *&tail)`

Comment: Why does `print_list` allocate a `new Student` and then immediately lose the pointer to it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me what will change in the implementation part?

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. It is working as per my expectations now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify the `head` and `tail` inside `main()`, you will have to pass the pointers by reference:

```
void add_student(Student *&, Student *&);
void print_list(Student *&);
```

Of course, you'll have to change your implementation too.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please tell me what will change in the implementation part, as I am really struggling with the part :( Sorry about asking about the implementation.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't make that clear. You're going to need to make your declaration match the header part of of the implementation. So the part that says `void funcname (...)`, the `...` part will have to match the declaration as well. The rest of the implementation should be okay as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes. I changed the implementation part as well to ```void add_student(Student *&head, Student *&tail)```. However, it is throwing some error ``` undefined reference to `print_list(Student *&)` ``` :(

Comment: Hmm. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58440844/edit) and post what part you changed and copy and paste the error you get?